# How to use a linked list when working with a class

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

So I have a class named **Student** and I have to make a list of students using linked lists.

Below you have my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Student
{
private:
    int grade;
    string name;
public:
    Student(int grade, string name)
    {
        this->grade = grade;
        this->name = name;
    }
    void getStudent()
    {
        cout << name << grade << endl;
    }

};

class Node {
public:
    Student student;
    Node* next;
};

void printList(Node* n)
{
    while (n != NULL)
    {
        n->student.getStudent();
        n = n->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node* studentList = NULL;

    studentList = new Node(); // Reported error at this line
    studentList->student = Student(1, "Matei");
    printList(studentList);

}
```

However I get an error: *the default constructor of "Node" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function*.

Please help me!

Comment: `std::list<Student>` is a linked list of `Student`s, though you'd probably run into the same error. When you create a `Node` you need to create its `Student` member. How do you want to create it? (hint: you need to call one of its constructors)

Comment: `Node` directly contains a `Student`, and this `Student` must be constructed before the body of the `Node` constructor is entered. Since `Student` does not have a default constructor, it cannot be automatically constructed, so the default constructor of `Node` cannot be used. You will have to specify the arguments for the `Student` constructor in the `Node` constructor's [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Comment: einpoklum has a better idea in their answer and is aiming for [Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we [compile your code](https://godbolt.org/z/E8Kfjb) (GodBolt.org), we get:

```
<source>:44:28: error: use of deleted function 'Node::Node()'
   44 |     studentList = new Node(); // Reported error at this line
      |                            ^
<source>:25:7: note: 'Node::Node()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   25 | class Node {
      |       ^~~~
<source>:25:7: error: no matching function for call to 'Student::Student()'
<source>:13:5: note: candidate: 'Student::Student(int, std::string)'
   13 |     Student(int grade, string name)
```

Let me interpret that for you:

You were trying to construct an instance of `Node` using the default (no-argument) constructor: `Node()`. But - does `Node` *have* a default constructor? You would think that it should, because you haven't deleted it, nor defined any other constructor.

... but this would be a mistake. You see, one of the fields of node is a `Student`; and the implicit default constructor of `Node` constructs the fields of `Node` using their own default constructors. Unfortunately, you *have* implicitly deleted the default constructor of `Student` by defining a constructor of your own.

So, what should you do?

1. Make the Node constructor take a `Student` (or `const Student&` etc.).
2. Change the last lines in your code to something like

   ```
   studentList = new Node(Student(1, "Matei"));
   printList(studentList);
   ```

---

PS - In examples here on the site, please use namespace-qualified identifiers such as `std::cout` and `std::string`, and include their relevant standard-library headers. Don't just write `cout` or `string`.

Comment: I think you mean to have curly braces rather than regular brackets. `new Node{...}`. Might as well go the distance with `new Node{{1, "Matei"}, nullptr};`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @user4581301 yes it has to be curly braces.

Comment: Can you guys help me with something else?

Comment: @MateiAnghel: Ask another question if you have another problem.